# Google gantt chart not updating height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-visualization

I am using the react component of Google's Gantt chart. The chart data is part of my component's state, I am updating it based on user action. I am calcuating the Gantt chart height based on the number of rows and pass this as the `height` prop.

```
<Chart
      chartType="Gantt"
      data={[columns, ...this.state.data_rows]}
      width="100%"
      height={(this.state.data_rows.length + 1) * 42}
      legendToggle
    />
```

Unfortunately, it seems like the update to the `chartData` prop is considered, but the height is not updated.

I have built a sandbox to show this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/l59199w8zl

If you click the "add row" button, a row is added, but the height remains constant. What can I do to make the Gantt chart grow as needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to update the SVG height;
I have modified the code to get `height` dynamically and set `SVG height` whenever a row is added.

https://codesandbox.io/s/7jy25q8mj

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data_rows: [
      [
        "Research",
        "Find sources",
        new Date(2015, 0, 1),
        new Date(2015, 0, 5),
        null,
        100,
        null
      ],
      [
        "Write",
        "Write paper",
        null,
        new Date(2015, 0, 9),
        daysToMilliseconds(3),
        25,
        "Research,Outline"
      ],
      [
        "Cite",
        "Create bibliography",
        null,
        new Date(2015, 0, 7),
        daysToMilliseconds(1),
        20,
        "Research"
      ],
      [
        "Complete",
        "Hand in paper",
        null,
        new Date(2015, 0, 10),
        daysToMilliseconds(1),
        0,
        "Cite,Write"
      ],
      [
        "Outline",
        "Outline paper",
        null,
        new Date(2015, 0, 6),
        daysToMilliseconds(1),
        100,
        "Research"
      ]
    ]
  };

  onAddRow() {
    let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    newState.data_rows.push([
      "Task" + newState.data_rows.length,
      "Some new task",
      null,
      new Date(2015, 0, 6),
      daysToMilliseconds(1),
      100,
      "Research"
    ]);
    this.data_rows++;
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  getHeight() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]) {
      document
        .getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
        .setAttribute("height", (this.state.data_rows.length + 1) * 42);
      document
        .getElementsByTagName("svg")[1]
        .setAttribute("height", (this.state.data_rows.length + 1) * 42);
    }

    return (this.state.data_rows.length + 1) * 42;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <span
          style={{ backgroundColor: "#0f0", cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={() => this.onAddRow()}
        >
          add row
          </span>
        <div id="chart_div">
          <Chart
            chartType="Gantt"
            data={[columns, ...this.state.data_rows]}
            width="100%"
            height={this.getHeight()}
            legendToggle
          />
        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it does not work in Firefox, because of the change in onAddRow(). However, if you remove this, it works in Firefox also. Can you update before I accept?

Answer (score 0):

For the gantt chart, there is a much simpler and more reliable method to determine and set the height of the SVG.

For example, if you have the svg container in a div with `id="chart_div"`, you can call the following function to get the height of the tallest drawn item inside the svg and set the svg height attribute to match the tallest item.

```js
function setChartSize() {
    let svg = document.getElementById('chart_div').querySelector('svg');
    let gs = Array.from(svg.querySelectorAll('g'));
    let maxHeight = 0;

    gs.forEach(el => {
        let height = el.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        if (maxHeight < height) maxHeight = height;
    });

    svg.setAttribute('height', maxHeight);
}
```

```html
<div id="chart_div">
  <svg height="100" widht="100%">
    <g></g>
    <g></g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

You can run this method after the chart is drawn, on the 'ready' event.

```
function drawChart() {
    let data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //... create your dataTable and fill it with data
    
    //set the width and an initial height (will be overwritten later)
    const options = {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100',
    };

    const chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', setChartSize);

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Hope this helps.